# Error in the .exe with PyInstaller, script with several dependencies

Tags: python, json, pandas, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have a GUI developed using Tkinter.

Everything runs smoothly in the script, however it prompts an error when launching the executable:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "general_funcs.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 199, in wrapper
  File "pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
  File "pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 563, in read_json
  File "pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 694, in read
  File "pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 716, in _get_object_parser
  File "pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 831, in parse
  File "pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 1079, in _parse_no_numpy
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

This is the configuration I used to run PyInstaller:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --icon "C:/Users/Marco Rodrigues/Programming/Code/plantasia/plantasia/utils/growth.ico" --add-data "C:/Users/Marco Rodrigues/Programming/Code/plantasia/plantasia/data;data/" --add-data "C:/Users/Marco Rodrigues/Programming/Code/plantasia/plantasia/images;images/" --add-data "C:/Users/Marco Rodrigues/Programming/Code/plantasia/plantasia/utils;utils/"  --paths "C:/Users/Marco Rodrigues/Programming/Code/plantasia/venv/Lib/site-packages" "C:/Users/Marco Rodrigues/Programming/Code/plantasia/plantasia/scripts/app.py"
```

I have tried several configurations, but I keep on having the exact same error.

You can check the repository on my github:

https://github.com/macrodrigues/plantasia

Comment: What's inside the utils folder? is it a python package?

Comment: There are only images in the utils folder, I assume it might be something related with the JSON file or the imports.